# Querying ISO Date with php mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to get values between dateTime range:

```
$where = array('date_time' =>array(
    '$gte' =>new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-08-09 10:23:00')),
    '$lte' =>new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-08-09 11:10:00'))
    ),
    'id'=>4
);
```

It is not working.

Comment: The query looks good. Are you sure there are docs matching this criteria. You can try removing date_time.$gte, date_time.$lte, and id filters one by one to see where the problem is.

Comment: Issue solved by using ".000Z" at end of date i.e  "2016-08-09 10:23:00.000Z"